# nsis installer starts in background

Tags: installation, nsis

I know this question was asked before. But I still have the problem. I was not able to figure out a solution that works for me.

What I have tried

- Use *BringToFront*
- Remove Everything from .OnInit function
- Remove .OnInit function completely

My code starts like this

```
!define MUI_WELCOMEPAGE_TITLE_3LINES
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE wel_pre
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW wel_show
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE lic_pre
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW lic_show
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "$(LICENSE_TEXT)"
```

Anything else I am missing or need to do more?

Comment: How are you starting the installer? Double-clicking it in Explorer?

Comment: Another applications starts my installer.

Comment: What is the name of this other application? Does it use CreateProcess or ShellExecute? Does it quit or hide right after starting the installer?

Comment: Its a c++ application it uses CreateProcess. It does not quit until nsis installer finishes its job.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me with and without STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW on Windows 8:

```cpp
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
STARTUPINFO si;
ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
si.wShowWindow = SW_SHOW;
TCHAR cmd[1+MAX_PATH+1+1];
ExpandEnvironmentStrings(TEXT("\"%Temp%\\NSISTest.exe\""), cmd, ARRAYSIZE(cmd));
if (CreateProcess(NULL, cmd, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
{
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
}
```

Perhaps you could provide some more information about your application? Does it have a visible window when it calls CreateProcess? Is this window the foreground window?

You could call `AllowSetForegroundWindow(ASFW_ANY)` to release the foreground-lock but it should not be necessary.

Comment: I do not have access to that code, probably I need to check in there.